# Web Crawlers keep finding non-existent URLs on my website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have two URLs:

- example.com/its-confusing
- example.com/about-me

Website crawlers don't find either of these. Instead they find this url:

- example.com/its-confusing/about-me

This seems to happen to almost all of my site URLs. Is there something wrong with my `.htaccess` file settings below?

Here's the .htaccess settings on my site:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^otherexample.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.otherexample.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https://example.com/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ detail.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ detail.php?page==$1

<Files .htaccess>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</Files>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Web crawlers know nothing about a ".htaccess" configuration file and they cannot somehow read it. If the web crawlers found those URLs then somewhere you have links pointing there. Maybe a broken sitemap somewhere? Maybe your application logic handing out broken links? But web crawlers do not make up URLs.

Comment: May I know, where is the location of the application logic related to urls? I used apache web server in this case.

Comment: WIth "application logic" I refer to the application you implemented in PHP.